# C++: Parsing a string of numbers with parentheses in it

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

This seems trivial but I can't seem to get around this. I have STL strings of the format `2013 336 (02 DEC) 04` (where `04` is the hour, but that's irrelevant). I'd like to extract the day of the month (`02` in the example) and the month as well as the hour.

I'm trying to do this cleanly and avoid e.g. splitting the string at the parentheses and then working with substrings etc. Ideally I'd like to use a `stringstream` and just redirect it to variables. The code I've got right now is:

```
int year, dayOfYear, day;
std::string month, leftParenthesis, rightParenthesis;
std::string ExampleString = "2013 336 (02 DEC) 04";

std::istringstream yearDayMonthHourStringStream( ExampleString );
yearDayMonthHourStringStream >> year >> dayOfYear >> leftParenthesis >> day >> month >> rightParenthesis >> hour;
```

It extracts the `year` and `dayOfYear` alright as `2013` and `336` but then things start going badly. `day` is `0`, `month` and empty string, and `hour` 843076624.

`leftParenthesis` is `(02` so it contains the `day` but when I try to omit `leftParenthesis` variable while redirecting the `yearDayMonthHourStringStream` stream `day` is also `0`.

Any ideas on how to deal with this? I don't know regular expressions (yet) and, admittedly, not sure if I can afford to learn them right now (timewise).

**EDIT**
OK, I've got it. Although this is like the billionth time when I could make my life just so much easier with regex, so I guess it's time. Anyway, what worked was:

```
int year, dayOfYear, day, month, hour, minute, revolution;
std::string dayString, monthString;

yearDayMonthHourStringStream >> year >> dayOfYear >> dayString >> monthString >> hour;
std::string::size_type sz;
day = std::stod( dayString.substr( dayString.find("(")+1 ), &sz ); // Convert day to a number using C++11 standard. Ignore the ( that may be at the beginning.
```

This still requires handling of `monthString`, but I need to change it to a number anyway, so that isn't a huge disadvantage. Not the best thing you can do (regex) but works and isn't too dirty. To my knowledge also vaguely portable and hopefully won't stop working with new compilers. But thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm sure you can discard the first character in `leftParenthesis`, resulting to what you wanted.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where `*scanf` does a better job than streams, since it can perform matching as well as input.

Comment: Not sure if you want to use boost, but Boost.Spirit is a perfect tool for this. [=> Example parser with parenthesis around number](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/complex___our_first_complex_parser.html)

Comment: @Angew It wouldn't be hard to create a manipulator which matches; I've done so in the past.

Comment: @Angew I've edited my answer to include the code using manipulators.  (Maybe someone who has some time should write up a proposal to add such a manipulator to the standard.  It's a common requirement, and as you point out, it's something that's easy with `scanf`, and so should be supported by `std::istream`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious solution *is* to use regular expressions (either
`std::regex`, in C++11, or `boost::regex` pre C++11).  Just
capture the groups you're interested in, and use 
`std::istringstream` to convert them if necessary.  In this
case,

```
std::regex re( "\\s*\\d+\\s+\\d+\\s*\\((\\d+)\\s+([[:alpha:]]+))\\s*(\\d+)" );
```

Should do the trick.

And regular expressions are really quite simple; it will take
you less time to learn them than to implement any alternative
solution.

For an alternative solution, you'd probably want to read the
line character by character, breaking it into tokens.  Something
along the line:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
std::string currentToken;
char ch;
while ( source.get(ch) && ch != '\n' ) {
    if ( std::isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) ) {
        if ( !currentToken.empty() ) {
            tokens.push_back( currentToken );
            currentToken = "";
        }
    } else if ( std::ispunct( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) ) {
        if ( !currentToken.empty() ) {
            tokens.push_back( currentToken );
            currentToken = "";
        }
        currentToken.push_back( ch );
    } else if ( std::isalnum( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) ) {
        currentToken.push_back( ch );
    } else {
        //  Error: illegal character in line.  You'll probably
        //  want to throw an exception.
    }
}
if ( !currentToken.empty() ) {
    tokens.push_back( currentToken );
}
```

In this case, a sequence of alphanumeric characters is one token,
as is any single punctuation character.  You could go further,
ensuring that a token is either all alpha, or all digits, and
maybe regrouping sequences of punctuation, but this seems
sufficient for your problem.

Once you've got the list of tokens, you can do any necessary
verifications (parentheses in the right places, etc.), and
convert the tokens you're interested in, if they need
converting.

EDIT:

FWIW: I've been experimenting with using `auto` plus a lambda as
a means of defining nested functions.  My mind's not made up as
to whether it's a good idea or not: I don't always find the
results that readable.  But in this case:

```
auto pushToken = [&]() {
    if ( !currentToken.empty() ) {
        tokens.push_back( currentToken );
        currentToken = "";
    }
}
```

Just before the loop, then replace all of the `if` with
`pushToken()`.  (Or you could create a data structure with
`tokens`, `currentToken` and a `pushToken` member function.
This would work even in pre-C++11.)

EDIT:

One final remark, since the OP seems to want to do this
exclusively with `std::istream`: the solution there would be to
add a `MustMatch` manipulator:

```
class MustMatch
{
    char m_toMatch;
public:
    MustMatch( char toMatch ) : m_toMatch( toMatch ) {}
    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& source, MustMatch const& manip )
    {
        char next;
        source >> next;
        //  or source.get( next ) if you don't want to skip whitespace.
        if ( source && next != m_toMatch ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        }
        return source;
    }
}
```

As @Angew has pointed out, you'd also need a `>>` for the
months; typically, months would be represented as a class, so
you'd overload `>>` on this:

```
std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& source, Month& object )
{
    //      The sentry takes care of skipping whitespace, etc.
    std::ostream::sentry guard( source );
    if ( guard ) {
        std::streambuf* sb = source.rd();
        std::string monthName;
        while ( std::isalpha( sb->sgetc() ) ) {
            monthName += sb->sbumpc();
        }
        if ( !isLegalMonthName( monthName ) ) {
            source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
        } else {
            object = Month( monthName );
        }
    }
    return source;
}
```

You could, of course, introduce many variants here: the month
name could be limited to a maximum of 3 characters, for example
(by making the loop condition `monthName.size() < 3 &&
std::isalpha( sb->sgetc() )`).  But if you're dealing with
months in any way in your code, writing a `Month` class and its
`>>` and `<<` operators is something you'll have to do sooner or
later anyway.

Then something like:

```
source >> year >> dayOfYear >> MustMatch( '(' ) >> day >> month
       >> MustMatch( ')' ) >> hour;
if ( !(source >> ws) || source.get() != EOF ) {
    //  Format error...
}
```

is all that is needed.  (The use of manipulators like this is
another technique worth learning.)

Comment: @James right, I think you're right. I may have been putting this off for far too long now. My attitude to regex is kind of the same thing as people eating doughnuts, pizza, smoking cigarettes, and not running every morning - everyone knows what is the right thing to do but we (typically) just never do it :P

Comment: @user657267 Definitely.  I tried to write it so that he could substitute `boost::regex` if he was using pre-C++11, however.  But maybe I should have preferred the raw string literal, because it makes it clear just how simple this regular expression is: it is purely linear, and involves none of the regular expression operators; just special names for the character classes.  As such, it could be a good way of starting to learn regular expressions.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh and you seem to be missing a \ before the last \\s.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I posted the two alternatives intentionally, so that you can see the difference.  Long term, however: you should learn both, and be able to use either without any problem.  There are problems where the tokenizer is the more appropriate solutions.  (And of course, tokenizers can be generated from regular expressions using `flex`.  Yet another tool worth knowing if you have to do much parsing.)

Comment: @user657267 Yup.  Fixed.  But it's worth noting that the largest problem with regular expressions might be debugging: the error messages only come at runtime, and aren't always that clear.  (Maybe a compiler could be extended to give a warning when the string initializing an `std::regex` isn't a legal regular expression.  Some compilers do this for `printf`, and the utility is much less, because the format parameter from `printf` is normally read from a locale dependent file.)

Comment: The manipulator solution will not work as-is, as `month` would gobble up the `)`.

Comment: @Angew Good point.  You'd probably want to have a class `Month`, with its own `>>` operator, which would (after skipping whitespace) only accept alphas.

Comment: @Angew Added the `>>` for months.  (Come to think of it, I don't think I've ever used `>>` directly on an `std::string` either.  Naively using whitespace as a separator doesn't seem to correspond to any real use case I've encountered; most of my non-numeric input must, in fact, accept white space as part of the field.)

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, you were totally right about regex, thanks for the motivation ;)

Answer (score 3):

@Angew +1 for `scanf()`.  It will do what you want in one line:

```
int day;
int hour;
char month[4];
int result = sscanf(ExampleString.c_str(), "%*d %*d (%d %3s) %d", &day, month, &hour);
if (result != 3)
{
    // parse error;
}
```

Comment: Re the +1: and fail the instant he (or anyone else) changes `char month[4]` into `std::string month;`.  Using `scanf` isn't valid in any professional code, since it is unmaintainable.

Comment: @JamesKanze You can't be serious.  Any programmer stupid enough to make a mistake like that isn't going to last long as a programmer.

Comment: Apparently, you have no experience in real life development.  Even highly experienced developers make such errors, all the time.  Which is why functions like `scanf` are generally banned in professional environments.

Comment: @JamesKanze Your statement is self contradictory.  Anyone who claims to be a "highly experienced developer", but who makes mistakes like that "all the time" is demonstrating that they are **not** highly experienced.  Either that, or they have no ability whatsoever to learn from their mistakes.  In either case, they won't last more than a few week where I work: that sort of incompetence will wind up being grounds for dismissal.

Comment: Obviously, you've never worked in a professional environment.  Highly experienced and very competent programmers _do_ make mistakes like this all the time.  No human being is perfect, and when several people are working on the same code base, it's all to easy for even the most competent to overlook such hidden dependencies.

Comment: @JamesKanze Did you read what I wrote?  I've been in the software industry for 30 plus years now, and never once have I made the mistake of trying to hand a `std::string` to `%s` in either `printf()` or `scanf()`.  To repeat, any so called experienced programmer that makes that sort of fundamental mistake on a regular basis will get fired where I work, and we have let go of a couple of people for precisely that sort of reason.  It would seem that we have considerably higher standards when it comes to hiring people.

Comment: So you're perfect.  I've never met such a person in my career, and all of the places I've worked have insisted that the code we write be maintainable by normal people, since they've not been able to find any perfect people to hire.  (This is a fundamental part of professional ontology, and not respecting it is enough to get you fired in most places.)

Comment: If you consider that having the necessary skill to avoid mixing `stl` (C++) and `scanf()` (C) inappropriately makes me perfect, then yes I most certainly am.  I most certainly did not claim that I never make mistakes, only that I haven't made a stupid mistake like that for the last 20 plus years.  Apparently you have vastly lower standards than we do: it is expected that programmers we hire know the difference between `char cStr[4];` and `std::string stlStr;`.  Let's face it, if you _don't_ know the difference between those two, you really should not be a professional programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Working example for regex http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac5a4c9269e94344

(no string parsing included)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //int year, dayOfYear, day;
    //std::string month, leftParenthesis, rightParenthesis;
    std::string ExampleString = "2013 336 (02 DEC) 04";
    regex pattern("\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*\\((\\d+)\\s+([[:alpha:]]+)\\)\\s*(\\d+)\\s*");

    // Matching single string
    std::smatch sm;
    if (std::regex_match(ExampleString, sm, pattern)) {
        cout << "year: " << sm[1].str() << endl;
        cout << "dayOfYear: " << sm[2].str() << endl;
        cout << "day: " << sm[3].str() << endl;
        cout << "month: " << sm[4].str() << endl;
        cout << "hour: " << sm[5].str() << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // If your data contains multiple lines to parse, use this version
    // unfortunately it will skip all lines that does not match pattern.
    ExampleString = "2013 336 (02 DEC) 04" "\n2014 336 (02 DEC) 04" "\n2015 336 (02 DEC) 04";
    for (sregex_iterator it(ExampleString.begin(), ExampleString.end(), pattern), end_it;
        it != end_it; ++it)
    {
        cout << "year: " << (*it)[1].str() << endl;
        cout << "dayOfYear: " << (*it)[2].str() << endl;
        cout << "day: " << (*it)[3].str() << endl;
        cout << "month: " << (*it)[4].str() << endl;
        cout << "hour: " << (*it)[5].str() << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Below is for debuggex, it does not accept `[[:alpha:]]` so its replaced with \w, although [a-zA-Z] would be better:

```
\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*\((\d+)\s+(\w+)\)\s*(\d+)\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wbRbBgZpXHAk2twy)

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added the regex visualization. :)

Comment: Using `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\\w+` for the month would fit his requirements closer.  (On the other hand, it's easy enough to check the string once he's captured it.)

Comment: Also (and I forgot it as well in my response): it would be a good idea to add a `"\\s*"` at the end, to allow trailing whitespace.  (If nothing else, `'\r'` is whitespace.  When reading a file under Unix which was written as text under Windows, all of the lines will have a trailing `'\r'`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I have added your suggestions, [[:alpha:]] will be better that \w - it will skip numbers and underscores

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use regular expressions, and you want a hack that looks as similar as possible to what you already have... you can just replace the parentheses in the string with spaces. (I'm not saying that this is a *good* solution, but it's worth knowing about.)

```
int year, dayOfYear, day, hour;
std::string month;
std::string ExampleString = "2013 336 (02 DEC) 04";

std::replace_if(ExampleString.begin(), ExampleString.end(), [](char c) { return c == '(' || c == ')'; }, ' ');

std::istringstream yearDayMonthHourStringStream( ExampleString );
yearDayMonthHourStringStream >> year >> dayOfYear >> day >> month >> hour;
```

Comment: It's a very good solution unless OP needs to make sure that strings not matching the pattern are rejected. But I guess he doesn't need that, so your answer is alright in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can make the stream approach work by reading the left- and right-parenthesis into `char` variables instead of strings, and having the `month` parsing stop when it sees a right parenthesis... gets a bit ugly though:

```
int year, dayOfYear, day;
std::string month;
char leftParenthesis, rightParenthesis;
std::string ExampleString = "2013 336 (02 DEC) 04";

std::istringstream yearDayMonthHourStringStream( ExampleString );
if (yearDayMonthHourStringStream >> year >> dayOfYear >> leftParenthesis
        >> day >> std::ws &&
    getline(yearDayMonthHourStringStream, month, ')') &&
    yearDayMonthHourStringStream >> rightParenthesis >> hour &&
    leftParenthesis == '(' && rightParenthesis == ')')
    ...use your variables...
else
    ...report bad input...
```

(`<iomanip>`'ss `std::ws` just used so the tolerance for `ws` is consistent throughout).